# Transferring data from my Java program into browsers (Chrome, IE)

Tags: java, browser

How can I transfer data, for example, login and password, from my Java program into browsers (Chrome or IE), when they open some page? For example, I have data of my Facebook account in DB in client-sided Java-application. It's necessary to send this info to my browser, so that the welcome page of Facebook wouldn't appear, that is the page of the account appears immediately. And if it's possible, when user fills in some form, the Java-application check that info, and if there is no such records in DB, suggest to create new one.

Comment: have you read about Java Servlets?

Comment: could you be clearer about the sequence of actions you want to happen? Do you want to instrument the browser using a client-side Java program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Java program is a desktop application or applet, the [`browse()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29) method of [`java.awt.Desktop`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) accepts a [`URI`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) that can include such [information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme), depending on the *scheme*. Java SE 6 is required.